# Button Click to change view in Fragment - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following:

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    signOutButton.setOnClickListener{
        Log.i("TAG", "logout tapped")
        auth.signOut()
        startActivity(Intent(activity,LoginActivity::class.java))
    }
}
}
```

The view loads, but when I tap the button to log the user out, I dont see a print out of the log and nor does the user logout and the view doesn't switch to the `loginActivity()`.

My button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signOutButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign out" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already returned the view the rest of the lines will never be called. It's unreachable. `return` be at the end of the function. Also, you will want to set the click listener after the view is created(`onViewCreated`) else you will get a `NullPointerException`.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    signOutButton.setOnClickListener{
        Log.i("TAG", "logout tapped")
        auth.signOut()
        startActivity(Intent(activity,LoginActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override the onViewCreated() function and write down your signout code there, Also initialize the signOutButton.